# How many nonzero solutions can the equation $x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}=1$ have?

Tags: combinatorics

Given an equation $x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}=1$ in the finite field $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ or $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. How many nonzero solutions can it have? I have tried paring the $x_{i}$ like 1 with -1 and then leave the odd term to be 1. But this method seems too rudimentary.

Comment: What do you mean by"non-zero?"

Comment: I mean the nonzero elements in the finite field $\mathrm{GF}(q)$.

Comment: Trivially the number of solutions is $q^{n-1}$. $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ can be anything, and you then set $x_n=1-x_1-x_2\cdots-x_{n-1}$. Not all of them can be zero. But was this really the question you wanted to ask??

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm afraid it wasn't. In the equation, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ are all unknowns. Their possible values are $1, 2, \dots, q-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why the last two terms? For whatever the first $n-1$ terms sum up to, there is always an element in $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ that when added to the first $n-1$ terms equals to 1, right? So there are $(q-1)^{n-1}$ possible solutions?

Comment: But the correct choice for the last variable may be zero. What I initially had in mind doesn't really work (so I deleted the second comment).

Comment: What is the magnitude of $q$?. It must be $q=p^m$ where $p$ is the characteristic of the field, so could be very large. How many solutions are there, say, for $n=5$ and $q=7^{100}$?

Comment: @Piquito $q$ is a given integer and yes, it can be very large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mid \sum x_i = 1, x_i\in\mathbb F_q\}$. So $A$ includes solutions where the $x_i$ can be zero, and $|A|=q^{n-1}$. Let $A_i$ be the set of elements of $A$ with $x_i=0$. You are seeking:

$$|A\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots \cup A_n)|$$

So this is a job for inclusion-exclusion.

$$|A\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n)|=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}q^{n-i-1} =\frac{(q-1)^n-(-1)^n}{q}$$

So, for example, when $q=2$, then the number of solutions is $1$ if $n$ is odd and zero if $n$ is even.

---

Another approach is to think in terms of matrices. Let $a_x(n)$ be the number of ways of writing $x\in\mathbb F_q$ as the sum of $n$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb F_q$. Then we see that $a_x(n+1)=\sum_{y\neq x} a_y(n)$, and $a_x(0)=\begin{cases}1&x=0\\0&x\neq 0\end{cases}$. This can be written by written $a_*(n)$ as a vector $\mathbf a_n$ then:

$$\mathbf a_n = (J-I)^na_0$$

Where $J$ is the $q\times q$ matrix of all ones, and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Now, $J-I$ has eigenvalue $-1$ with all vectors $(v_0,\dots,v_{q-1})^T$ with $\sum v_i=0$ and eigenvalue $q-1$ with eigenvector $(1,1,1,\dots,1)^T$.

So write $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ in terms of these eigenvectors. Then:

$$(1,0,\dots,0)^T=\frac{1}{q}(1,1,1,\dots,1)^T+\frac{1}{q}(q-1,-1,-1,\dots,-1)^T$$

Writing $v_{q-1}=(1,1,\dots,1)^T$ and $v_{-1}=(q-1,-1,-1,\dots,-1)^T$ we see that:
And thus $$(J-1)^n (1,0,\dots,0)^T=\frac{1}{q}\left((q-1)^n v_{q-1}+(-1)^{n}v_{-1}\right)$$

This means that 
$$a_n(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{(q-1)^n + (-1)^n(q-1)}{q}&x=0\\
\frac{(q-1)^n-(-1)^n}{q}&x\neq 0\end{cases}$$

This matrix is essentially the same as Andre's approach - the polynomial $x^2-(q-2)x-(q-1)$ is just a way of stating the same recursion that he found.

Comment: I looked up the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, but I couldn't quite see how you used that to get the sum. And from that sum, how did you get the nice fraction expression? Could you expand your solution a little?

Comment: If you are new to inclusion-exclusion, I'm not sure I can clarify much. There are $\binom{n}{i}$ subsets of $1,2,\dots,n$ if size $i$, and the size of the intersection of $i$ of the $A_j$ is $q^{n-1-i}$. The second part of the equality comes from the binomial theorem: $(q-1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}q^{n-i}$. You have to subtract $(-1)^n$ and divide by $q$ to get the formula I got from inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Thanks! Why is $|A|=p^{n-1}$? Since each individual $x_{i}$ ranges from 0 to $p-1$, shouldn't it be $p^{n}$?

Comment: You can pick the first $n-1$ values freely from the $p$ values, but then the condition $x_1+\cdots + x_n=1$ determines the value of $x_n$. @Orca_1

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be the number of non-zero solutions. Then for any fixed non-zero element $c$, there are $a_n$ non-zero solutions of $x_1+\cdots +x_n$. For we can go back and forth from sum $1$ to sum $c$ by multiplying through by a suitable constant.

We first count the number of solutions that have $x_n\ne 1$. This is $(q-2)a_{n-1}$. For $x_n$ can be chosen in $q-2$ ways. And for each such choice  $c$ we need to count the number of non-zero solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}=1-c$. There are $a_{n-1}$ of these.

For the solutions with $x_n=1$, the term $x_{n-1}$ can be any non-zero element $d$, as long $x_1+\cdots+x_{n-2}=-d$. So there are $(q-1)a_{n-2}$ solutions.

We have obtained the recurrence
$$a_n=(q-2)a_{n-1}+(q-1)a_{n-2}.$$
The characteristic polynomial is $x^2-(q-2)x-(q-1)$, which has roots $q-1$ and $-1$.

Thus $a_n=A(q-1)^n+B(-1)^n$. The constants $A$ and $B$ can be found by using $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$. We get $A=\frac{1}{q}$ and $B=-\frac{1}{q}$.

Comment: Pretty sure it is $A=\frac{1}{q}$, Your answer gives non-integer values for $a_n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks, yes, from $a_0=0$ we get $A=-B$.  I see we agree. Your way is more efficient.

Comment: Perhaps, but your way is more natural - an inductive approach, and it explains the form better - the $(q-1)^n$ and $(-1)^n$ seem to pop out as magic in my approach.